# Are there any general best practices for validation methods?

Tags: c#, architecture

I was creating a common interface to verify operationality of data providers when a question came to my mind.

Essentially the method i'm looking at has a signature like `Task<bool> TryConnectAsync();`

While that method clearly indicates whether or not a provider will be able to work, it provides no generic way to point out what to do, if it cannot work (false).

Looking at for example the AspNetCore.Identity package, that issue was resolved by using the return type [IdentityResult](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Core/IdentityResult.cs) for any method which can succeed/fail on top of providing additional information on how to resolve issue or point out what went wrong.

I do not want to use exceptions in this case, since a connection failing is not a scenario which is entirely unexpected and would make the method handling wonky since the method is either true, or it throws an exception which delivers details on what went wrong.

I also do not want to dump that information just into logs - i want a library consumer to be able to decide whether to display that information or not.

So my question is:

#### Is an informational class which provides success/failure like AspNetCore.Identity the standard practice, or what other ways of handling this are there?

For google: How to handle success or failure of a method and provide additional information.

Not sure if the question is right here tho. Might be better suited for SE.

Comment: Why not `Task ConnectAsync()` and just let the exception bubble up? Or capture it within the ConnectAsync method, and wrap it in a custom exception which you then throw? After all, if you can't connect, it is an exceptional circumstance. If the consumer doesn't want to show the exception, they can catch it (which is made easier with custom exception objects, provided you document them).

Comment: @john exceptions should be used if you are uncertain what happened and how to resolve it. It's a different case if i have enough information to provide meaningful information on how to resolve an issue instead of throwing an exception for a case which is expected to happen potentially. So yeah - intentionally not using exceptions here. I've had this scenario in the past with other boolean methods. Using exceptions to resolve domain specific issues rather than code issues just feels very wrong.

Comment: I think we both agree that exceptions shouldn't be used to direct program flow when a program is running as intended. But a connection failure is an example of a program not running as intended. Unless it's a scenario that is likely to happen very often, I think that this is exactly the kind of time exceptions should be used. Is this something that is going to fail often as part of the intended running of the application?

Comment: I think [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159096/return-magic-value-throw-exception-or-return-false-on-failure) will help address your query anyway.

Comment: @john yes we agree to some degree, but in this case i want to verify if i can connect. if it were Task ConnectAsync an exception would make sense ofc.

Comment: @john it does address it yes - seems like in this case a handling similar to IdentityResult is a common way to address issues which are not related to code. Thanks